# Showing the network activity with mvvmlight

Tags: xamarin.ios, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.android, mvvm-light

I've been banging my head against a wall here.

I have a xamarin app that uses mvvmlight. It's close to completition, but it's been pointed out that the network activity spinner is not showing on any platform.

Understanding that this is a platform specific operation, is there a way I can bind the button that triggers the the spinner and on return from the network activity, cancel the spinner?

I did consider something like

```
this.BtnDoSomething.SetCommand(Events.Click, () => {startSpinner; this.ViewModel.DoStuff});
```

but that won't call back on completion to remove the spinner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a cleaner solution to this would be something like this:

1. Have a Property called `IsBusy`
2. Just before you start loading stuff you set it to `true`
3. Right after you are done loading stuff set it to `false`

In your view bind visibility to a Spinner of some sort to that property. All this behaviour should go into the ViewModel rather than be done in your View.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Xamarin, but can't you do something lke:

```
this.BtnDoSomething.SetCommand(Events.Click, () => 
{
    startSpinner(); 
    this.ViewModel.DoStuff(stopSpinner)
});
```

Then your `DoStuff` method would take a callback as parameter and call it when done:

```
public void DoStuff(Action callback)
{
    // Do some asynchronous stuff
    // call callback
    if (callback != null)
    {
         callback();
    }
}
```